# How to reduce index size in SOLR?

Tags: solr

I am not able to reduce the index size of Solr. Is there any method to do this? I tried to change the tokenizer and filter.

It would be better if you could explain how to calculate Index Size.

Comment: Why do you need to reduce the index size? Usually - remove stored fields and store less information. Changing tokenization and filters won't do much, except in those cases where it expands a token into many smaller parts / versions of itself. Just tokenization and processing won't change much.

Comment: Is performance what you're worried about, have you thought about sharding, master/slave configuration and so on?

Comment: There is not big difference in size after removing stored field.

Comment: Have a read here it is old, but still the best I know https://lucidworks.com/blog/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/ otherwise, post your schema.xml. Without it all suggestions are fishing in the dark :)